# Arithmetic Shift Operation In verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an Verilog module which has to shift one bit at a time.
Please help me completing the module.

```
module shift_right1 (
  output logic [15:0] shifted,
  input  wire  [15:0] unshifted,
  input  wire   [3:0] amt );

  localparam int width = 16;

  always @* begin 
    automatic int limit = width - amt;

    for ( int i=0; i<limit; i++ ) begin
      shifted[i] = unshifted[i+amt];
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: `localparam int`, `automatic int` I do not know any guides that show to write verilog like this. What are you trying to do by labelling a variable automatic? Shifting 1 bit at a time, would normally imply 1 bit per clock cycle, and you do not have a clock in your example. could you try to clarify the question. Well done on including some code though it is good to see.

Comment: actually it is a part of my homework project and professor asked me to change the code to take one bit at a time as input.

Comment: Module shift_right1 is supposed to perform a logical right shift on a 16-bit quantity. Your solution should assign shifted one bit at a time, as does the existing code. (In other
words, don’t just use the right shift operator.) The testbench output might provide clues to what
the problem is. Hint: The problem can be fixed with one or two lines of code

Comment: @user3159419: Looks like you just want to complete the current code, which is only missing the assignment to bits [width-1:limit]. For logical shift, just change my code to `shifted[i] = 1'b0;` in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic shift keeps the sign while shifting. After the for loop, you will need to set the sign of the shifted value. Something like this may work:

```
for ( int i=limit; i<width-1; i++ ) shifted[i] = unshifted[width-1];
```

Notice that **all** digits that are inserted from the left side should be equal to the sign bit of the unshifted value, i.e. `unshifted[width-1]`.

```
Example:

Shifting 1011000 by 3, should be: 1111011
Shifting 0011000 by 3, should be: 0000011
```

Comment: The comments mention ' logical right shift ' not an arithmetic shift, but it is not clear just from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is **take one bit at a time as input**. This implies the input is 1 bit, right shifting the old data. Which is an implementation of a serial to parallel convertor.

```
module shifter(
   input               dat_rx, //1bit data input    
   input               clk,
   output logic [15:0] dat_tx  //Parallel output
);
   always @(posedge clk) begin
     dat_tx <= {dat_rx, dat_tx[15:1]}; //Next input and right shift
   end
endmodule
```

A combinatorial version requiring external flip-flop:

```
module shifter_comb(
   input dat_rx,
   input  logic [15:0] dat_old,
   output logic [15:0] dat_tx
);
   always @* begin
     dat_tx = {dat_rx, dat_old[15:1]}; //Next input and right shift
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: Morgan, Thank you for the answer. But in the above stated code, i need to use the same variables as my prof' stated i.e amt [3:0]. I have to put up an additional logic but not change the variables or so.

Comment: @user3159419 Glad your finding it useful, questions and answers are more useful (preferred) on this site that are helpful to many people, and it is not a code writing service. You have not stated what **amt** is in the question or answered the question I left on your question. If the port list is fixed the question should state that, and explain clearly what the ports are.